# Can't Import to File Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two file dart, In First dart i wrote this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color bcolorg13 = Color(0xaed6dc);
Color bcolorg12 = Color(0xff9a8d);
Color bcolorg11 = Color(0x322e2f);
Color bcolorg21 = Color(0x24695c);
Color bcolorg22 = Color(0xc18e60);
Color bcolorg23 = Color(0xeed8d5);
Color bcolorbg = Color(0xFFFFFF);
```

but when i import in another file, it show error,Colors doesn't work when i call it,

```
import 'package:electronic_maintenance/sizeconfig.dart';
import 'package:electronic_maintenance/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:electronic_maintenance/Color.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: bcolorg12,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Login',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: bcolorg12,
        ),
      ),
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: bcolorg13,), onPressed: null),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `0xFF` you lost two `FF` character 
code snippet

```
Color bcolorg13 = Color(0xFFaed6dc);
Color bcolorg12 = Color(0xFFFF9A8D);
Color bcolorg11 = Color(0xFF322e2f);
Color bcolorg21 = Color(0xFF24695c);
Color bcolorg22 = Color(0xFFc18e60);
Color bcolorg23 = Color(0xFFeed8d5);
Color bcolorbg = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color bcolorg13 = Color(0xFFaed6dc);
Color bcolorg12 = Color(0xFFFF9A8D);
Color bcolorg11 = Color(0xFF322e2f);
Color bcolorg21 = Color(0xFF24695c);
Color bcolorg22 = Color(0xFFc18e60);
Color bcolorg23 = Color(0xFFeed8d5);
Color bcolorbg = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: bcolorg12,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Login',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: bcolorg12,
        ),
      ),
      leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: bcolorg13,
          ),
          onPressed: null),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```